# Problems with Python directories, pip and new libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, path, pip

I have problems running Python programs on Windows10 x64 (either via console or Pycharm) since I've installed numpy, django, wheel et al via pip on the console. Unfortunately I can't make heads nor tail of the error message.

Running for example (in Windows Powershell):

```
PS C:\Users\cqqkie> python
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cqqkie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\cqqkie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 26, in <module>
    WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
>>>
>>> x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

Possible causes:

1. I have recently reinstalled Python 3.8.2 as Administrator (usable for all users)
   in "C:\Program Files\Python38" and when I log to my computer as admin and run the code via console, the above code works. (after pip installing as user I've pip installed numpy as Admin)
2. Next, I've installed the problematic packages/libraries first via and got the warning:

```
C:\Users\cqqkie>pip install wheel <br />
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable 
Collecting wheel   Using cached wheel-0.34.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel   WARNING: The script wheel.exe is installed
 in 'C:\Users\cqqkie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts' which is not on 
PATH.   
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this 
warning, use --no-warn-script-location. 
Successfully installed wheel-0.34.2
```

3. I've tried adding:

   'C:\Users\cqqkie\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Scripts'
   'C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts'
   'C:\Users\cqqkie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32'

   to my systems variables as well as user variables in environment variables.

It's not working and I'm pretty confused at this point. What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: `ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung` ==> not a compatible(?) Win32 application. Is this a 32bit / 64bit compatibility issue?

Comment: OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (in translation), I'm using x64 Windows. I'll edit in OP

Comment: I've installed the 64bit version of Python. Is this somehow not compatible with numpy?

Comment: I'm not sure about that -- I was just trying to translate the warning in case it was helpful to other readers.

Comment: Hm ok, I think the translation should be (valid) instead of (compatible) though

Comment: The onus is on you the poster to translate your post - not on me trying to be helpful. Hope you get an answer.

Comment: Absolutely :) I edited accordingly.

Comment: So, do you now run 32bit programs on a 64bit PC or 32bit on a 32bit PC?

Comment: I had the  Windows x86-64 version of Python installed and ran it on 64bit computer. After posting, I uninstalled and reinstalled the 32 bit Python version and ran it. First time installed in '''C:\Programe Files''' and second time in '''C:\Programe Files(x86)''. From Powershell I was able to run the numpy code (when I changed to Administrator). But not as <C:\Users\My_Name>